# Z3 issues with propagating equalities under quantifiers

Tags: z3, quantifiers

I have the following simple example for which Z3 times out:

```
(set-option :produce-models true) 
(define-fun T_0 (($in1 Real) ($in2 Real)
  ($out Real) ($assms Bool) ($prop Bool)) Bool 
   (and (= $assms (< $in1 $in2)) 
        (= $prop (=> $assms (and (< $in1 $out) (< $out $in2))))))

(declare-fun $in1$0 () Real)
(declare-fun $in2$0 () Real)
(declare-fun $out$0 () Real)
(declare-fun $assms$0 () Bool)

(assert (forall (($out$0 Real) ($assms$0 Bool)) 
           (not (and (T_0 $in1$0 $in2$0 $out$0 $assms$0 true)))))
(check-sat)
```

Now, if we simplify the assertion, propagating the equality, z3 immediately returns UNSAT (as expected):

```
(define-fun T_1 (($in1 Real) ($in2 Real)
    ($out Real) ($prop Bool)) Bool 
      (and  (= $prop (=> (< $in1 $in2) (and (< $in1 $out) (< $out $in2))))))
(declare-fun $in1$0 () Real)
(declare-fun $in2$0 () Real)
(declare-fun $out$0 () Real)
(assert (forall (($out$0 Real) ($assms$0 Bool)) 
           (not (and (T_1 $in1$0 $in2$0 $out$0 true)))))
(check-sat)
```

This example seems to show that Z3 does not propagate equalities under quantifiers. For example, the following assertion works (yields UNSAT):

```
 (assert (forall (($out$0 Real)) 
     (and (not (= true (=> (< $in1$0 $in2$0) 
          (and (< $in1$0 $out$0) (< $out$0 $in2$0))))))))
```

Is there any way to get z3 to propagate equalities, or to choose another search strategy that uses the equation?

Comment: Manually expanding two cases in the quantifier body also immediately results in UNSAT: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/X1Nv.